# Find registry key value and return registry key value path

Tags: c#, networking, registry

I have a code which search registry key value in specific key path.
In registry key `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`
find all keys with `0000 , 0001 , 0002 , 0003` and so on at the end of registry key. `{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` . In each key ( for example `0007` ) are subkey called `NetCfgInstanceId` which holds network interface card ID value , like this `{C80949A4-CEDA-4F29-BFE2-059856D7F745}` . If finds value, method returns key path !
Problem is  an error `Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'` in

```
foreach (string key_value in key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId").ToString())
```

Full code is

```
public string key_path(RegistryKey root, string root_path, string search_key)
{
    string path = string.Empty;
    foreach (string keyname in root.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = root.OpenSubKey(keyname, true))
            {

                foreach (string key_value in key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId").ToString()) 
                {
                    if (key_value == search_key)
                    {
                        string reg_path = (string)key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId");
                        path = reg_path;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        path = "Can't find key !";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Security.SecurityException)
        {
            //Do nothing !!!
        }
    }
    return path;
}

private void kryptonButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var answer = key_path(Registry.LocalMachine, @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}", "{C80949A4-CEDA-4F29-BFE2-059856D7F745}");
    MessageBox.Show(answer);
}
```

How can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Foreach takes an enumerable value.  You are using a string as that value, so the compiler wants a character variable in the foreach.  In other words, your call to GetValue(...).ToString() does not return an array of strings, it returns one string.  foreach( var x in stringval ), var is a char.

Consider something like this instead ...

```
var kind = key.GetValueKind("NetCfgInstanceId");
if (kind == RegistryValueKind.MultiString)
{
    foreach (var key_value in (string[])key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId"))
    {
        if (key_value == search_key)
        {
            string reg_path = (string)key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId");
            path = reg_path;
        }
        else
        {
            path = "Can't find key !";
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming you are expecting a multistring in the reg key.  You can use the following if it could be a single string ...

```
if (kind == RegistryValueKind.ExpandString
   || kind == RegistryValueKind.String)
{
    var key_value = (string)key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId");
    if (key_value == search_key)
    {
        path = key_value;
    }
    else
    {
        path = "Can't find key !";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please write full code with this ? Something i didn't understand. :(

Comment: I get error var key_value = key.GetValue("NetCfgInstanceId"); /// key din't found

Comment: I find solution .. ! Never take care for this !

Comment: I added a cast to string.  Also, cleaned up second code example some.